# Change title of UIButtons based on index, just like UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray, uisegmentedcontrol

When I use a `segmentedControl` I would do the following to set titles based on unknown `indices` (before runtime):

```
[self.segment setTitle:@"this Title" forSegmentAtIndex:next];
[self.segment setTitle:@"another Title" forSegmentAtIndex:after];
```

I'm trying to replicate `UISegmentedControl` using `UIButtons`. How can I achieve the above code using `UIButtons`?

I was thinking to add the `buttons` to an `array`, but if I do that, I wouldn't be able to set the title through the `array index`. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can put the buttons in the array and use the array index must like you do for the segmented control.

```
NSArray *buttons = ... // your array of buttons
[buttons[next] setTitle:@"this Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttons[after] setTitle:@"another Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

[button setTitle:@"After" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];